# Investing tips with lower box 3 taxation (NL)

Tags: taxes, stocks, etf, netherlands

Any tips on investing in the Netherlands with the ability to lower your box 3 'wealth tax' annual payments? Maybe something special like the british ISA or so exists in NL as well, which allows tax free investing? The idea of a pension plan is already fully maxed out for us, and we have to pay a lot of taxes each year for the ETFs we own. NL has a high capital gains tax (30% or so) which makes it very difficult to stay motivated when investing long term as each year we get more and more taxed.
Any tips from those who know more about NL taxation would help greatly..

We considered lowering our mortgage but since our interest is so low (1.4%) it doesn't make too much sense. I would love to know specifically about ETFs as I don't like speculative investing in 'green' stocks that are tax free up to 30K or so..

Comment: NL does not have capital gains tax in box 3. You are taxed on the basis of a fictional return and taxed around 30% (31 from top of my head). Works out to a bit below 2% of capital for anything but savings accounts. Also note that the fictional gain amount is under review and tax returns that include box 3 income are not finalized as of 2022 tax year.